# The type or namespace name 'SyncListString' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? in mirror

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity3d-mirror, cs0246

Hey i am beginer and i am making a multiplayer game using mirror by watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w0Dzb4axdcw&list=PLDI3FQoanpm1X-HQI-SVkPqJEgcRwtu7M&index=3 this video in this video he has maded match maker script and i have maded it step by step but don't know why i am getting this error i have seen code many times and all the things are same but he is not getting any error but i am plzz help this is my code and plzz explain in simply i am beginner

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

using Mirror;

namespace MirrorBasics {

    [System.Serializable]
    public class Match {
        public string matchID;
        public SyncListGameObject players = new SyncListGameObject ();
        
        public Match(string matchID, GameObject player) {
            this.matchID = matchID;
            players.Add (player);
        }

        public Match () { }
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class SyncListGameObject : SyncList<GameObject> { }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class SyncListMatch : SyncList<Match> { }

public class MatchMaker : NetworkBehaviour {

    public static MatchMaker instance;

    public SyncListMatch matches = new SyncListMatch ();
    public SyncListString matchIDs = new SyncListString ();

    void Start() {
        instance = this;
    }

    public bool HostGame (string _matchID, GameObject _player) {
        if (!matchIDs.Contains(_matchID)) {
        matchIDs.Add (_matchID) ;
        matches.Add (new Match (_matchID, _player));
        Debug.Log ($"Match generated");
        return true;
        } else {
            Debug.Log ($"Match ID already exists");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static string GetRandomMatchID () {
        string _id = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            int random = Random.Range(0, 36);
            if (random < 26) {
                _id += (char)(random + 65);
            } else {
                _id += (random - 26).ToString ();
            }
        }
        Debug.Log($"Random Match ID: {_id}");
        return _id;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Like SyncListGameObject create SyncList with string like this.

```
public class SyncListString: SyncList<string>()
```

Then

```
public SyncListString matchIDs = new SyncListString();
```

I made lobby/matchmaking by this tutorial too :)